# How can i stop reading "Direct touch area. Use the rotor to enable direct touch for this app" in our iOS app accessibility?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accessibility, uiaccessibility

When the voice-over is ON, I am always hearing this "Direct touch area. Use the rotor to enable direct touch for this app". How can I get rid of this, this is so much annoying to the end users.

I have found this but does not help.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663529

Comment: I'm not Apple expert, but direct touch areas are ment for apps which have their own way of handling touch input. It's very specific, for games for examples, and unless you effectively handle touch input on your own in an accessible way, you are going to make your app totally inaccessible. Is that really wanted? If no, you shouldn't use direct touch areas at all.

Comment: It is always keep saying that "Direct touch area. Use the rotor to enable direct touch for this app" even if i stop using the Direct Touch from Settings.